# Celebrity vertices in graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite, simple, undirected graph. For $v\in V$, let $N(v) = \{w\in V:\{v,w\}\in E\}$ and let $\text{deg}(v) = |N(v)|$. Moreover, we set $L(v) = \{w\in N(v): \text{deg}(w) < \text{deg}(v)\}$, and we say that $v\in V$ is a *celebrity* if more than half of $v$'s neighbors have fewer neighbors than $v$ does, or more formally, if $$2\cdot |L(v)| > \text{deg}(v).$$
By $\text{Celeb}(G)$ we denote the set of celebrities of $G$.

A real number $r\in [0,1]$ is called a *simultaneous celebrity bound* if for *every* simple, finite, undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ we have
$$\text{Celeb}(G) \leq r\cdot |V|.$$
Obviously, $1$ is a simultaneous celebrity bound.

**Question.** If $S\subseteq [0,1]$ is the set of simultaneous celebrity bounds, what is the value of $\inf S$?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I believe that the final inequality is just written in the wrong direction by mistake. Then the question becomes more meaningful. The word "smallest" before $r$ supports this idea. Let the OP to clarify.

Comment: @fedja Oh I see, you may be right. Then a lower bound is $2/3$, as $K_{n,n,n+1}$ has $2n$ celebrities.

Comment: Apologies for the unclear formulation, and the word "smallest" is not optimal in the post. I will amend this. Oh right, and I got $\leq$ wrong, it should have been $\geq$ -- will fix this!!

Comment: Apologies again for the confusion I created with my errors.

Comment: In other words, you are looking for the supremum of the ratio $\operatorname{Celeb}(G)/|V(G)|$ over all finite simple graphs $G$, is that right?

Comment: @bof - that is correct

Comment: Given @EmilJeřábek 's answer, it might be interesting to ask what is the infimum here if we restrict to graphs with certain nice properties. For example, if the chromatic number of the graph is bounded, can we do better?

Comment: @JoshuaZ The construction in my answer can be easily modified so that the resulting graph is bipartite. (E.g., just drop the edges inside $V_0$. Then $V_0$ will also consist of non-celebrities, but this is of no consequence.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only bound is $r=1$. I will construct graphs below whose celebrity ratio is arbitrarily close to $1$.

Fix an arbitrarily large parameter $k$. The graph will have vertex set $V=V_0\cup V_1\cup\dots\cup V_k$, where all vertices in $V_i$ have degree $4k-2i+1$. Their neighbours will be distributed so that

- each $v\in V_0$ has $2k$ neighbours in $V_0$, and $2k+1$ neighbours in $V_1$;
- for $0<i<k$, each $v\in V_i$ has $2k-i$ neighbours in $V_{i-1}$, and $2k-i+1$ neighbours in $V_{i+1}$;
- each $v\in V_k$ has its $2k+1$ neighbours in $V_{k-1}$.

This ensures that all vertices in $V_0\cup\dots\cup V_{k-1}$ are celebrities. Let $n_i=|V_i|$. Counting the number of edges between $V_i$ and $V_{i+1}$ in two ways, we see that the sizes must satisfy
$$\frac{n_{i+1}}{n_i}=\frac{2k-i+1}{2k-i-1}$$
for $i<k-1$, and
$$\frac{n_k}{n_{k-1}}=\frac{k+2}{2k+1}.$$
Thus, we put
$$n_i=\frac{(2k+1)(2k)}{(2k-i+1)(2k-i)}n_0\qquad\text{for $i<k$,}\qquad n_k=\frac{2k}{k+1}n_0,$$
where $n_0$ is chosen as a multiple of $(2k)!$ so that all $n_i$ are integers. To satisfy the degree requirements above, the edge set consists of:

- a $2k$-regular graph with vertex set $V_0$;
- for each $i<k-1$, $n_i/(2k-i-1)=n_{i+1}/(2k-i+1)$ copies of $K_{2k-i-1,2k-i+1}$ between $V_i$ and $V_{i+1}$;
- $n_{k-1}/(2k+1)=n_k/(k+2)$ copies of $K_{2k+1,k+2}$ between $V_{k-1}$ and $V_k$.

Since $n_0\le n_i$ for each $i$, the total size of the graph is at least $(k+1)n_0$, whereas the number of non-celebrities is $n_k<2n_0$, thus the proportion of celebrities is at least
$$1-\frac2{k+1}.$$

Comment: Beautiful, thanks Emil!